# how to pass data from module.export function to an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a simple Node/Express app and am trying to pass data from a javascript function to a template (powered by jade).

The javascript function looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  getFeatures: function() {
    var request = require("request")

    // ID of the Google Spreadsheet + Base URL
    var spreadsheetID = "abcdefg-123456";
    var sheetID = "od6";
    var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/" + spreadsheetID + "/" + sheetID + "/public/values?alt=json";

    //empty array for features
    var features = [];

    //get the features
    request({
        url: url,
        json: true
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            var data = body.feed.entry;
            data.forEach(function(item) {
                var obj = {
                    pub: item.gsx$publication.$t,
                    date: item.gsx$date.$t,
                    title: item.gsx$title.$t,
                    url: item.gsx$url.$t,
                }
                features.push(obj);
            });
            console.log("features", features"); //prints array containing all objects to server console
            return features;
        }
    });
  }
};
```

And the main app looks like this:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var jade = require('jade');

var gsheets = require("./gsheets.js"); //pulls in module.exports from above
var featuresOld = require('../private/features.json'); //original json pull (a single array of objects)

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var app = express();

// defining middleweare
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '../../public'));

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/templates');

...

// features route
app.get('/features', function(req, res) {
  var path = req.path;
  res.locals.path = path;
  var features = gsheets.getFeatures(); //attempting to call js function above
  res.render('features', {features: features}); //trying to pass data into a template
});
```

The first function successfully prints an array of objects to the server console, so I think the error lies in how I'm calling it in the main app.js. (Please note, it's only printing when I have it entered as `gsheets.getFeatures();`, not `var features =  gsheets.getFeatures();`.)

Please also note that the `featuresOld` variable is an array of objects that has been successfully passed through to a jade tempalte, so the error is not in the `res.render('features', {features: features});` line.

I'm sure this is pretty straightforward, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you to look into Promises (either Native or using a library like [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/)).
But without using Promises or generators and keeping things simple, you can pass a callback function that will be called only when the values are retrieved. Within this function you can render the template.

(Note that your function currently does not return anything)

```
module.exports = {
  getFeatures: function(callback) {
    var request = require("request")

    // ID of the Google Spreadsheet + Base URL
    var spreadsheetID = "abcdefg-123456";
    var sheetID = "od6";
    var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/" + spreadsheetID + "/" + sheetID + "/public/values?alt=json";

    //empty array for features
    var features = [];

    //get the features
    request({
        url: url,
        json: true
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            var data = body.feed.entry;
            data.forEach(function(item) {
                var obj = {
                    pub: item.gsx$publication.$t,
                    date: item.gsx$date.$t,
                    title: item.gsx$title.$t,
                    url: item.gsx$url.$t,
                }
                features.push(obj);
            });
            console.log("features", features"); //prints array containing all objects to server console
            callback(features); // call the rendering function once the values are available
        }
    });
  }
};
```

Now in your main app, you just pass a callback to the function

```
app.get('/features', function(req, res) {
  var path = req.path;
  res.locals.path = path;
  gsheets.getFeatures(function(features) {
    res.render('features', {features: features}); //trying to pass data into a template
  });
});
```

Basically, your request function is asynchronous - the request will run in background and the callback function will be called with the value once it's retrieved. In the meantime, the rest of the code will keep running (in your case you'd try to use the value even though it hasn't been retrieved yet).
If you need to do something that depends on that value, then you'd have to put that code in a callback function which would be called when the value is available (as showed above).
Promises provide a nice API for doing that. There are also new features ES6 that helps you better organise asynchronous code.

Comment: Ok cool thank you.  It printed so quickly in the console that I didnt realize I had to do a callback function.  Also, what's the difference between `callback(features);` and `return features;`? I haven't seen `callback()` used before

Comment: in your code ``return features;`` is not doing anything, it's just returning the value back to ``request`` which doesn't expect it, so it just gets lost. In the code I've sent, ``callback`` is just the name I've chosen for the function you pass as a parameter when calling ``getFeatures`` (f you change the argument name to ``done`` or anything else, it would also work). It's a very common practice in node.js where most calls are asynchronous

Comment: Ok cool thank you, I think that makes sense.  I am getting `ReferenceError: callback is not defined` at the `callback(features)` line when I navigate to the features route. Any idea what's causing that? @AlexCorreiaSantos

Comment: I can't see exactly what you have, so I'll try to guess what's more likely to be happening. Did you forget to add callback as an argument to the function? ``getFeatures: function(callback) {``